# Slideshow to fill Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I posted a this question last night, but have completely rewritten it because I think it was confusing people, and I also have provided an example to illustrate my problem....

**I have a slideshow that I would like to fill a div completely.** Right now, if someone visits my site from a narrow browser viewport, the slideshow will only fill the width but not the entire height, therefore leaving space at the bottom of the div.

**I would like the slideshow to proportionally scale to fit and cover the entire div, even if cropping from the sides is necessary.** Does this make sense what I am asking?

Here's the example: If you visit it right now from a wide or full screen browser window, the images probably fill the entire div. **But if you narrow your window and refresh, you will see the bg color at the bottom of the div.** Example: http://mudchallenger.com/a-responsivef.html

How can I get this slideshow to fill the div?

Thank you!!

**I should also add, I'm NOT trying to make this fill the screen as a background. I just want it to fill the div.

Comment: Even if you just want the image to fill a div - the easiest way is with a background. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p7eUZ/5/ or check out this slider I wrote: www.drewbble.com/angular-slider/

Comment: @drew_w      
Thanks...Actually, I'm trying to get the background slideshow images to fill the div only, not the page. Perhaps this link will help me explain better... The slideshow at the top, I want it to fill the div. If the browser is too narrow, you will see green at the bottom of the div. mudchallenger.com/a-responsiveb.html

Comment: There really isn't any difference between filling a div and the page. If you open up the angular slider and right click on the main slide viewer you can change `.slide-viewer.taller` css class in your browser's inspector to have a percentage width smaller than 100% you can see this in action. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the height of the image to 100% and let the width be automatic. This is because the images are of landscape orientation. Then, make sure you have the overflow (maybe just overflow-x) attribute of div.slideshow set to hidden. This will allow the image to scale to the div (the frame) rather than to itself. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/krh121791/rXep9/.

```
HTML
<div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
   <img src="http://mudchallenger.com/a-images/backgrounds/bg-1.png"  />
</div>

CSS
.slideshow{
  height:100%;
  width:600px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.slideshow img{
  height:100%;
}
```

A note, you would set the width to 100% and overflow-y to hidden if you have a portrait picture.

Comment: This solution will only work as long as the aspect ratio of the div is never more than that of the image. If this should happen, the page will still end up with "bars" on the LHS and RHS of the image.

Comment: @drew_w - That's exactly what I am currently experiencing...
And Drew, in the fiddle you referenced, (I have used before with just a static bg image)  How would I apply the attributes on lines 5&6 of the CSS without "background"?
Lines 5 & 6:
background: url("") center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

Assuming I would apply it to this:
}
.slideshow{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.slideshow img{
  height:100%;
}

Comment: @HoustonGuy I used the images in your example. As long as you take the short side of the image and match it to the long side of the div, using the 100% value, the example should work. Setting overflow:hidden will remove any scroll bars. Also, the background image trick will work as well.

Comment: @user1663209, thank you. My brain seems to be fried at the moment or something.  I still can't seem to get it to work.   If I increase the container in your example to 100% wide, there will be bars on both sides of the image.  I want to image to fill width:100% of the container/screen.  The jsfiddle provided is exactly right, however I want to do this with the slides and just can't figure it out. Please shoot me.

Comment: My fiddle link was incorrect. Also, idk if this helps, but in the link you provided, the body has a margin:8px;. If you set the margin to 0, the white bars disappear.